# How can I resolve my build error?

Tags: java, java-8, jmonkeyengine

I can build the project on Windows 8.1. When trying with Ubuntu I get this error message

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>       The method interpolateLocal(Vector2f, Vector2f, float) is undefined for the type Vector2f   NavMesh.java    /spaceworld/src/jme3tools/navmesh   line 230    Java Problem

The offending code is not mine.

```
if (d1 < d2){                           
  intersectionPoint.interpolateLocal(wall.getPointA(), wall.getPointB(), distBlend);
  newWayPoint = new Vector3f(intersectionPoint.x, 0, intersectionPoint.y);
}else{
  intersectionPoint.interpolateLocal(wall.getPointB(), wall.getPointA(), distBlend);
  newWayPoint = new Vector3f(intersectionPoint.x, 0, intersectionPoint.y);
}
```

I've included cai-nmgen-0.1.2.jar and the jme3 jars just like I did on windows to make it work. Why won't it build?

Comment: The library you are trying to use is OS dependent?

Comment: `com.jme3.math.Vector2f` has `interpolate(Vector2f, Vector2f, float)` but not `interpolateLocal`.  Are you sure you didn't change something you shouldn't have?

Comment: @DavidWallace No. I changed the versions of the jars. I will try with exactly the same now. But it's not good that I can't run latest version of everything.

Comment: Well, naturally, if you're using different versions of the jars, you can expect some things to be different.  Most likely, the operating system has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Now I tried with exactly the same jars and I get an os dependant other error about rendering. Thank you for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Vector3f and interpolate vs. interpolateLocal](http://hub.jmonkeyengine.org/t/vector3f-and-interpolate-vs-interpolatelocal/28590/9)  blog post, it seems there have been some break changes on this method between version 3.0.10 and 3.1 of `jme3` library.

So you'd better check the version you're using on Windows 8.1 and figure out if the older dependency (or some other package transitive dependency) is somehow in the build path.

Also try on your Ubuntu your code with version `jme3` library version 3.0.x